# Jquery.min.js local copy not calling window load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-api, local

I am using jquery for focus of tabs. When i used :

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

in my jsp then the window.load function works good, but when i downloaded jquery.min.js and added in js folder.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>` like this.

Now window.load function is not working.

`<script type="text/javascript">`

```
$(window).load(function() {
    alert('Hello');
    if($("#updatetemp").val()=="TRUE"){
    $("#update_link").click();}
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're loading the script, that you haven't put it in the wrong path? Check the web console of your browser for errors. If you see a 404 error, that may be the problem.

Comment: Why are you placing the $(window)load in the html?

Comment: My HTML page contains HTML, JavaScript and Jquery. The page loads fine there are no any errors. My HTML page contains Two tabs. On load of page i want second tab to get selected automatically.so i am using Jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the way to use JQuery locally..

```
jQuery(window).bind("load", function($) {
    var msgtemp= jQuery("#updatetemp").val();

    if(msgtemp=="TRUE"){
    jQuery("#update_link").click(function() {
        }).click();
    }
});
```

Instead if $ symbol i just used jQuery attribute and it worked.